# Is there a more detailed or customizable help page for OSGi commands?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, equinox, gogo-shell

**Background:** OSGi environment on equinox. For the execution of custom comands I use the gogo shell (org.apache.felix.gogo.command, org.apache.felix.gogo.shell).

I can show all available commands (including my own custom ones) with `felix:help`.
My problem is that the output is not as detailed as I require it to be. It looks like:

```
...
gogo:gosh
gogo:grep
gogo:history
gogo:not
gogo:set
gogo:sh
gogo:source
gogo:tac
gogo:telnetd
gogo:type
gogo:until
scr:config
scr:disable
...
```

Is there a way to extend that page to be more like a man-page or at least showing the arguments of the underlying Java method (at least for my own commands)? In the worst case I would have to write a `help` method which prints the commands (at least my custom ones) in a man-page like manner.

Maybe someone can save me time by giving me another option :-). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following for more information

```
  help [<scope>:]<command>
```

The help is generated via the `@Descriptor` and `@Parameter` annotations that are in the Gogo runtime bundle. This is rather extensively described the [Extending Gogo Shell](https://v2archive.enroute.osgi.org/appnotes/gogo-cmd.html) in the unfortunately archived original OSGi enRoute.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for :-). Thank you very much! Its hard to find such information for OSGi unfortunately.